# Ambassador vs. Orchestrator services

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, microservices, orchestration, ambassador

I'm reading up on building resilient systems. I came across the Ambassador and Saga (Orchestrators) design pattern.

These two design patterns seem to be doing the same thing, with the exception of the Ambassador service co-existing on the Host application.

What makes these two patterns different?

Comment: Why do you think they are doing the same? As far as I know they are unrelated so I am curious why do you think they do the same

Comment: After much research, I have found that they can be the same thing. An Ambassador service is a proxy for legacy or applications that do not support desired features (security, performance, throttling etc.). The legacy app will make point-to-point calls to the Ambassador service, which ultimately relays that request to Third-Parts targets. As part of that Proxy, it can become an Orchestrator itself. It doesn't have to delegate the Orchestration to another service.

Comment: Ohh I think I see your confusion. The SAGA pattern can be implemented in orchestration and in choreography way. In the former case there is a saga coordinator who knows what to do (or undo) whenever an action succeeds (or fails).  In the latter case this knowledge is not centralized rather spread across each participant. Each component knows from who to anticipate some input and  who should be notified in case of completion or failure of its own job.

Comment: The SAGA pattern itself is all about to deal with distributed transaction. It is a sequence of updates and notifications on several distributed subsystems. The Ambassador pattern is a specialization of the Sidecar pattern which is all about to colocate some cross-cutting concern with the microservices. It provides isolation and encapsulation at the same time. As you can see SAGA and Ambassador have not too much in common. But the orchestration and ambassador can be compared.

Comment: Do you want me to leave a post?